# Connecting Laravel website with Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: database, laravel, dynamics-crm

We currently have a custom made Laravel CRM application for our staff that is connected to a website for orders, customer registration and a few questionnaires.

We have recently started migrating our CRM application to Microsoft Dynamics as it is getting a little out of date.

My question is: what is the best practice for having our website linking with Dynamics?

I have been looking at portals for the questionnaires we currently have on the site, so i only really need orders and registrations to be passed between the site and dynamics.

Thanks

Comment: You could check out Dynamics 365 Portals and the Voice Of the Customer solution for the questionnaires (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/voice-of-customer/install-solution)

Comment: The new best practice to to use CRM's WebApi (built on REST); How are you currently connecting your Laravel app?